# How i can call webview form the other screen

Tags: android, layout, dialog, webview

i have 3 diferents screens: main(contains one image), dialog(contains another image) and browser(contains a webView) and one activity source, ok, in the activity source I call the dialog on click image in main layout, then the dialog shows another image and I want when click in the dialog image, the app change main layout for browser layout and then the browser load an specific URI and then close the dialog.

My code dont work becouse i dont know how i need use the webView in separate layout, for example, to call in dialog i need use dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView1) or in main only findViewById(R.id.webView1), but this not work now and the app crash...

My code:

```
       ImageView imgMain = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMain1);

    imgMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Android");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        //Boton de cerrar del dialog Android
        Button closeDialog = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeDialogBT);
        closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        //click en imagen juegos del dialog android
            ImageView imgDialog = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgDialog1);
            imgDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
        });


    }
    });
```

Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to start WebView of one Activity from other activity.

It will be better to start activity containing WebView from your "imgDialog" with the intent.

and send URL string in that intent's extras.

in next step load webview with the URL string fetched from intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this will help you

```
public class Example extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.translate);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```